# PHP if else with or doesn't work on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a wordpress theme. I can't figure out a (probably simple) issue! The code below does something with post-data. I want this code to work on 2 template files. It works on home.php, but i nee it to work on blog.php as well. I tried:

```
<?php if ( !is_page_template('templates/home.php') ) || ( !is_page_template('templates/blog.php') ) { ?>
```

But that didn't work. How do I fix this? Any thoughts? Thanks! :)

```
    <ul class="post-meta clr">
        <li class="meta-date">
            <?php _e('Posted on','wpex'); ?>
            <span class="meta-date-text"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
        </li>
        <?php if ( !is_page_template('templates/home.php') ) { ?>
            <?php if(isset($fist_category)){ ?>
                <li class="meta-category">
                    <span class="meta-seperator">/</span><?php _e('Under','wpex'); ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $category_url; ?>" title="<?php echo $category_name; ?>"><?php echo $category_name; ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if( comments_open( $post_id ) ) { ?>
                <li class="meta-comments comment-scroll">
                    <span class="meta-seperator">/</span><?php _e('With','wpex'); ?>
                    <?php comments_popup_link( __( '0 Comments', 'wpex' ), __( '1 Comment',  'wpex' ), __( '% Comments', 'wpex' ), 'comments-link' ); ?>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Is it executing all that code on even when using the blog template?  Are you sure that it's actually using the blog.php template?

Answer (score 1):

In the code you've tried your if statement will always be true.

The original version will execute the code if the user is not viewing a page that uses the `templates/home.php` page template.

In your modified version it will execute the code if the current page is not using `templates/home.php` or it's not using `templates/blog.php`. The only way that code won't fire is if the current page template is both home.php and blog.php which isn't possible.

Instead you need to use:

```
if ( ! ( is_page_template( 'templates/home.php' ) || is_page_template( 'templates/blog.php' ) ) ) { 
    // code here.
```

Or:

```
if ( ! is_page_template( 'templates/home.php' ) && ! is_page_template( 'templates/blog.php' ) ) {
    // code here.
```

Comment: For some reason it still didnt work. Only on the home.php, I fixed it in a different way.